# How can I change the length of a text_field in rails?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-3, textfield

So I have this text field

```
<%= f.text_field :body, placeholder: "Make an offer ", :maxlength=>"254" %>
```

right now it takes up 100% of the width of the box it is in. I want it to take up like 95%. So far I have tried (from other forum posts)

adding `:columns => "50"` this didn't affect it. I tried
putting on an html tag , `:html => { :id => "offer_form" }` and then putting in my css file

```
#offer_form { width:50%;}
```

this didn't work

any other suggestions?

edit:

I realized that in my css file I have under /*forms*/

```
input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  width: 98%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: auto !important;
  margin-bottom: 15px;

}
```

and when i change the width here it works. but it affects all of the forms in the entire app (obviously)(ie they are all 98%). Is there a way that I can id just this field so that I can edit its width independently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use CSS. The width of the field isn't related to its maximum characters.

```
input.body {
  width:95%;
}
```

Comment: that didn't affect it. Are there any other pieces of code that I could show you that might help?

Comment: That code probably *won't* affect it, unless your `<input>` happens to have a class of `body`. You are meant to apply the CSS to *your specific* classes/identifiers.

Comment: ohh ok. I think I know what is going on. I have edited my question

Answer (score 24):

add `:size=>"50"` option to text_field

```
<%= f.text_field :body, :size=>"50", placeholder: "Make an offer ", :maxlength=>"254" %>
```

Comment: that give me an undefined method "size" error. Any idea why? I thought size would just be a css quality.

Comment: If you're getting that error, it's because you left off the `:`. It's `:size`, not `size`. This answer might make your textbox smaller, but if you truly want to make your textbox 95% of the width of the parent, this cannot possibly help you. You need CSS.